# Python nesting elif,for

Tags: python, function, for-loop, if-statement, nested

Is it possible to write a for inside elif?
i have many elif statements and i want my last elif statement to have a for inside elif how to write nested elif in PYTHON

```
def victory(see,z):
if see[0]==see[1]==see[2]==z:
        print(z,"wins")
    elif see[3]==see[4]==see[5]==z:
        print(z,"wins")
    elif see[6]==see[7]==see[8]==z:
        print(z,"wins")
    elif see[0]==see[3]==see[6]==z:
        print(z,"wins")
    elif see[1]==see[4]==see[7]==z:
        print(z,"wins")
    elif see[2]==see[5]==see[8]==z:
        print(z,"wins")
    elif see[0]==see[4]==see[8]==z:
        print(z,"wins")
    elif see[2]==see[4]==see[6]==z:
        print(z,"wins")
    elif for blank in see if blank=="_" or"__"or"___":
            print("game not finished")
```

Comment: why `for` what exactly are you checking?

Comment: Please explain more what you try to do, this is unclear, do you just want to check is a value is in a list of values, or do an action for several values

Comment: is it possible to write a for inside elif?

Comment: for inside elift or elfi with for?

Comment: for inside elif

Answer (score 0):

Since it's your last elif, change it to else and create a for loop inside the else block. You can check your conditions inside the for loop then.

Also, you can try switch statement like code instead of numerous if elif else statements

`else:
    [print('game not finished') for blank in see if <condition>]`

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a list comprehension:

```
elif [blank for blank in see if blank in ["_", “__", “___"] ]:
    print("some text")
```

If the list comprehension ends up with nothing in it, it is considered ‘falsy’ and the elif won’t be taken.

Comment: while using elif if one condition is true it gets executed but in my case the above statement is getting executed everytime i run my code

Answer (score 0):

If you're checking for certain values in a list, you can use `in` instead of looping over the whole list:

```
if see[0]==see[1]==see[2]==z:
    print(z,"wins")
elif see[3]==see[4]==see[5]==z:
    print(z,"wins")
# ... lots of other elifs here
elif "_" in see or "__" in see or "___" in see:
    print("game not finished")
```